# w3wp process using 100% cpu and not attached to any of the application pool

Tags: windows, sharepoint

SharePoint server 2010  is having 2 w3wp process which is not attached to any of the application pool in the system(IIS -> Worker Process Not listing) and not listing using appcmd command. But it is using 100% CPU and not able kill through Task Manger.

[image]

Comment: ok, this looks like Server 2008, so use the Win7 WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt/revision/2.aspx) and analyze the CPU usage with xperfview: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pigscanfly/archive/2008/03/02/using-the-windows-sample-profiler-with-xperf.aspx

Comment: have you tried the WPT? Do xperf/xperfview show you the cause of the cpu usage?